# Video and audio out of sync after stream recording

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I have a problem. I recorded a live stream and the recorded file ended up with video lagging audio. And it is progressive. It starts with some ms at the beginning and getting more and more as the video continues. At the end of the video is about 5 seconds desync.

Here are the parameters from MediaInfo:

```
Format                      : MPEG-4
Format profile              : Base Media
Codec ID                    : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                   : 8.25 GiB
Duration                    : 4 h 46 min
Overall bit rate mode       : Variable
Overall bit rate            : 4 127 kb/s
```

Video:

```
ID                          : 1
Format                      : AVC
Format/Info                 : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile              : High@L3.1
Format settings             : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC      : Yes
Format settings, Reference  : 4 frames
Codec ID                    : avc1
Codec ID/Info               : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                    : 4 h 46 min
Source duration             : 4 h 46 min
Bit rate                    : 3 926 kb/s
Width                       : 768 pixels
Height                      : 576 pixels
Display aspect ratio        : 4:3
Frame rate mode             : Variable
Frame rate                  : 29.581 FPS
Minimum frame rate          : 0.004 FPS
Maximum frame rate          : 121.294 FPS
Color space                 : YUV
Chroma subsampling          : 4:2:0
Bit depth                   : 8 bits
Scan type                   : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)          : 0.300
Stream size                 : 7.85 GiB (95%)
Source stream size          : 7.85 GiB (95%)
mdhd_Duration               : 17171632
Codec configuration box     : avcC
```

Audio:

```
ID                          : 2
Format                      : AAC LC
Format/Info                 : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                    : mp4a-40-2
Duration                    : 4 h 42 min
Source duration             : 4 h 46 min
Bit rate mode               : Variable
Bit rate                    : 192 kb/s
Maximum bit rate            : 304 kb/s
```

Could you please shed some light on the solution?
How can I fix it in FFMPEG?

Comment: For accurate repair, you'll have to do it manually in a video editor. The crude solution is to resize one of the streams to match the duration of the other.

Comment: @Gyan thank you for your reply :) But i need the exact steps and commands to perform this. I have tried millions way with no success. Any input?

Comment: You should do it in a video editor, visually.

Comment: @Gyan I would prefer doing it with ffmpeg rather than anything else. I tried, though. No positive result